# Neo4j-Browser: Query does not return result but displays no error in addition

Tags: neo4j

I have run the following query

```
MATCH p=((s:Station {})-[:VERBINDUNG*]-(t:Station)) 
RETURN s.name, t.name, count(p) as pfade ORDER BY pfade DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I know it has to traverse a lot of relationships but there is no problem with the Java heap space as I monitor the ressources in the task manager. 
After one hour of running no error is displayed, but in addition the symbol which shows that the query is running is disappeared as well and no result can be seen.

As I look into the task manager it seems that the query is still running because the same ressources are used. How do I know if the query will ever finish  and will the result get displayed?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `allShortestPaths` instead? Because all paths can (depending on your graph) really be billions of paths **per pair**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the shape of your graph this query can get super expensive due to unlimited variable path length. Also it's a global query without any defined start point(s). Even worse you apply an `ORDER BY` which prevents the query from returning its results in streaming mode.

I guess you should rethink what result you expect from your query. Maybe you can limit the depth, maybe limit start and end points. Do you really want all the paths or are you just interested in the shortest one? If so, there's a `shortestPath` function.

Have you tried to press the close symbol "x" in the result pane? This should terminate a running query.

To check if you run into memory issues, look into `messages.log`.

Comment: I only want to run that query once because I am interested to know what's the maximum of paths which exist between two randomly picked nodes. That's the reason I can't set a limit neither use the shortestPath-function. So I have to run the query that way, don't I?

Comment: If you want to traverse all the things, there's no way to get around it. Maybe refactoring your graph structure could help - but this would be a lengthy discussion not suitable on SO.